# Win 7: Possible to use one task bar icon open both 32 & 64 bit versions of an app?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, taskbar, jumplist

I have to use both the 32 and 64 bit versions of some apps. There are two different exe's for these. I hate having two of the same icons for these apps pinned to the task bar.

Is there a way using the jump list or a keyboard shortcut + mouse click  or something that would let me use one icon to open both exe's?

Comment: I just found this by accident: http://www.blogsdna.com/5636/winstack-group-number-of-applications-in-same-icon-on-windows-7-taskbar.htm. It's pretty much exactly what I had in mind. I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of simply because they are different EXE files.

What you can do though is a sort of work around... but it isn't that good and a bit annoying.

Somewhere on your computer, out of the way, create a new folder.

Create a shortcut to both applications.

Right click on an empty part of the taskbar and go to `Toolbars` then `New toolbar`. Select the location of your folder and choose `Select Folder`.

[image]

You should now have a group on the taskbar where you can launch both applications from... However, this **only** deals with launching the applications and doesn't really help your problem - I hope it is better than nothing, but I know of no solution to do exactly what you want.

As for Jumplist, this is simply a feature of the actual application based on what the developer has chosen so maybe you can request a feature.

Comment: This is pretty close but not sure it's worth it just for 2 icons. 

I didn't know this was possible though, and I was looking for something like this... am now using it for a folder containing .bat's to RDP into several different machines I use often.

Answer (score 0):

> I hate having two of the same icons
>   for these apps pinned to the task bar.

there's a remedy for that:

right click on either one > Properties > Change Icon

Comment: ha, thanks. I realized this was possible, but it's not that the images are the same that is bothering me. It's that essentially the same program is taking up two spots on my taskbar.

Comment: assign hotkeys to each executable and remove the icons altogether, saves you even more space. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**7stacks**](http://www.alastria.com/index.php?p=software-7s) and define 1 stack for the 2 versions (32-bits and 64-bits) of the application.

You can use the application icon as the stack icon for a better look.